# Does "display:none;" ignore div's position to the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website I have a slideToggle div that contains some images, very big. When this div opens, I need the images to slideIn one by one **when entering the viewport**.

With my code, the div opens, but then the images slide in all at the same time (as if they were a single block).

But if I remove `"display: none;"` from my slideToggle div and I leave it open as a starting point, the script works perfectly.

I was wondering if `"display: none;"` somehow ignores the div's position to the viewport.

This is the slideToggle script I am using (if it helps): https://jsfiddle.net/5efuhytm/

Comment: I think this should answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all code needed to reproduce the issue you are seeing (an [mre]). You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: `display: none` removes the element from the flow of the document, including calculations of size and position.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
display: none;
```

Use

```
 visibility: hidden;
```

This is because display: none will remove the entire dom element from the document. Whereas visibility: hidden will just hide the dom element. In this case, if you don't want to change the viewport hide go with the visibility property.

Refer this for more details, https://stackoverflow.com/a/133064/7544289

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS remove `display:none` in `#show-images`:

```
/*Panel that slides open*/
#show-images
{

    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;

}
```

And add this code (because what you want to hide is just Image.)

```
#show-images img
{
   display: none;
}
```

Change the JS adding `#show-images img`

```
$(function()
  {
     $("a#toggle").click(function()
          {
           $("#show-images img").slideToggle(800);
           $("#toggle").toggleClass("fade");
            return false;
            });
  });
```